# @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST) after submit got HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I have a  wired behavior in this controller. I have two methods Get to prepare information to show in html form and POST to get de submit:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class NotificationController {

    final String  JSP_NOTIFICATION_01="pages/sendPush/createNotification";
    final String  JSP_NOTIFICATION_02="pages/sendPush/createNotificationStep2";


    @RequestMapping(value ="/admin/notification/newNotification",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newNotification( Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        //prepare  info to fill html form

        request.getSession().setAttribute("notificacion", notification);
        return JSP_NOTIFICATION_01;
    }


    @RequestMapping( value ="/admin/notification/sendNotification", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveNotification(@ModelAttribute("notForm") SendNotificationModel notForm,
                                      Map<String, Object> model,HttpServletRequest request) {


        //Get all information from HTML form

        System.out.println("llego.."+resultado);

        model.put("resultado", resultado);

        return JSP_NOTIFICATION_02;
    }   
}
```

**JSP**

```
        <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/notification/sendNotification" method="post" commandName="notForm">
                <form:hidden path="clientName"  />
                <form:hidden path="clientCode"  />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>topics:</td>
                <td><form:select path="topics" items="${topicList}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>users:</td>
                <td><form:select  multiple="true" path="users" items="${userList}"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tipo de despliege :</td>
                <td><form:select path="tipoNotificacion" items="${tipoNotificacionList}" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
```

After submit the POST method Receive the request as always, but after the return spring throw 405 error :

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
type Status report
message Request method 'POST' not supported
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

I'm using Spring  4.1.3 and tomcat8

thanks!!!

Comment: make sure you are providing exact parameters to your post method

Comment: @koutuk What difference would that make? Why would wrong parameters cause a 405?

Answer (score 2):

remove @RequestMapping(value ="/admin/notification/sendNotification") from controller

Comment: sorry, I tried using  global   RequestMapping in the class  and separate in each  method

Comment: @kuhajeyan sir, you are a life saver, I've been trying to find the solution for like hours and this simple trick did it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The annotation @RequestMapping can be used both at class and method level. When used at class level it is applied to all the methods. For example see the below code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {
    private final AppointmentBook appointmentBook;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> get() {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForToday();
    }
    @RequestMapping(path = "/{day}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date day, Model model) {
        return appointmentBook.getAppointmentsForDay(day);
    }
}
```

As in the above controller code /appointments is relative and it is applied to all the methods below. Any @RequestMapping at the start of method is added to the relative path.However note that @RequestMapping is not compulsory at class level. Go through the below official documentation for further understanding.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 1):

I fixed  adding one method, success (GET). in POST method I put a redirection and works

Reference http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-display-validate-and-submit-form-example/

```
@RequestMapping( value ="/admin/notification/sendNotification", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveNotification(@ModelAttribute("notForm") SendNotificationModel notForm,
                                  Map<String, Object> model,HttpServletRequest request) {

    NotificationDetails newNot = new NotificationDetails();//(NotificationDetails)request.getSession().getAttribute("notificacion");

    String resultado= "Probando" ;
    System.out.println("llego.."+resultado);

    model.put("resultado", resultado);

    return "redirect:/admin/notification/sendNotification/success";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/notification/sendNotification/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String success(Model model)
{
    return JSP_NOTIFICATION_02;
}
```